# Multiple media query is not working on ie10

Tags: css, media-queries, internet-explorer-10

For my css, I have a couple of media queries for ie10...

```
    @media screen and (max-width :1510px), screen\0{
      div.jw-menu-3col-sm li a .menuItem {
       padding: 0 12px; 
      }
    }


     @media screen and (min-width :1650px), screen\0{ 
       div.jw-menu-3col-sm li a .menuItem {
         padding: 0 16px;  
        }
      }
```

For some reason when I change the size of the screen it is not 'catching' the correct media query. Is there a reason why?

Answer (score 0):

[IE10 will interpret `screen\0` as `screen`](http://blog.keithclark.co.uk/moving-ie-specific-css-into-media-blocks), which means it treats it as a valid media query, and always apply both rules based on that query, making your min/max-width media queries irrelevant to IE. As a result the second rule will always take precedence over the first rule in IE.

It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish by combining the `screen\0` hacks with your proper media queries. If you want IE8 to always use the second rule, I would suggest just duplicating that rule into a new stylesheet and hiding that stylesheet in conditional comments, and losing the `screen\0` hacks from your main stylesheet.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is check for multiple screen sizes like it does in chrome and firefox. I did try it the following way:

Answer (score 0):

The comma at the end of each condition `, screen\0` means OR. So any screensize will be picked up by both media queries and apply both. You should also use `max-device-width` rather than `max-width` for accuracy

Instead use

```
@media screen (max-device-width: 1510px) {
...
}
```

etc. Make sure you have `viewport` set in the `<head>` of your HTML files as well.